# intent method (onActivityResult) wipeout previous listview stored data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I am trying to create a group of phone contacts in `CreateGroup.java` . So, for that purpose, I go to a new activity named `ContactsView.java` using an `Intent`. There I a get list of all contacts. When I click a contact from that list, it gets the name of that contact item and returns it back to the previous activity named `CreateGroup.java`. But when I try to add more contacts, it is replacing the previous added item in the `listview`. I am unable to add more than one contact in my list.

Please someone help me!!

```
CreateGroup.java 


    public class CreateGroup extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textView;
    ListView show;
    ArrayList<String> addArray=new ArrayList<String >();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_group);

 ImageButton next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButtonAddContacts);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewtst);
            show= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ContactsView.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            });
        }


 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch(requestCode) {
                case (0) : {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        String newText = data.getStringExtra("CName");
                        addArray.add(newText);
                        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (CreateGroup.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
                        show.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                   break;
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

here is ContactsView.java

```
    public class ContactsView extends ActionBarActivity {
        String namecsv="";
        String phonecsv="";
        String namearray[];
        String phonearray[];
        ListView lv1;


        ArrayList<String> list_items= new ArrayList<String>();

        //declare a variable for counting of selected items.
        int count=0;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);


            lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            list_items.add("one");
         Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()){
String name= phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                String phonenumber= phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                if(name!=null){
                    namecsv+=name + ",";
                    phonecsv+=phonenumber + ",";
                }
            }
            phones.close();
            namearray=  namecsv.split(",");
            phonearray=phonecsv.split(",");


            final ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,namearray);
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);


            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String msgname = namearray[position];
                    String msgnum = phonearray[position];
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msgname + " " + msgnum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                    resultIntent.putExtra("CName", msgname);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

I have updated my code according to the answer provided. but still facing the same problem. its only show only on  last add item in the listview. previous item removes.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
           case (0) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String newText = data.getStringExtra("CName");
                    textView.setText(newText);
                    addArray.add(newText);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    show.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please could you remove the commented lines and also improve your code format just in order to get a more clear code and a better question

Comment: @Robert i have reformatted my code. Please Check it

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` as very first thing, there but only when you face `requestCode` that is not handled by your code. In other words, this should be added to `switch` block, in `default` section. Other thing is that you should not set new adapter each time. So this:

```
addArray.add(newText);
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (CreateGroup.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
show.setAdapter(adapter);
```

should be replaced by:

```
addArray.add(newText);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

which simply adds data to your current array then notify the adapter (which you need to create in `onCreate()` additionally of course) about the change in dataset.

Comment: Sir i have updated my code. But problem not solved...only showing one recent added contact name. please help!